# How to change the default number of top and bottom row

Tags: python, pandas

By default, pandas shows you top and bottom 5 rows of a dataframe in jupyter, given that there are too many rows to display:

```py
>>> df.shape
(100, 4)
```

|  | col0 | col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 7 | 17 | 15 | 2 |
| 1 | 6 | 5 | 5 | 12 |
| 2 | 10 | 15 | 5 | 15 |
| 3 | 6 | 19 | 19 | 14 |
| 4 | 12 | 7 | 4 | 12 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 95 | 2 | 14 | 8 | 16 |
| 96 | 8 | 8 | 5 | 16 |
| 97 | 6 | 8 | 9 | 1 |
| 98 | 1 | 5 | 10 | 15 |
| 99 | 15 | 9 | 1 | 18 |

I know that this setting exists:

```py
pd.set_option("display.max_rows", 20)
```

however, that yields the same result. Using `df.head(10)` and `df.tail(10)` in to consecutive cells is an option, but less clean. Same goes for concatenation. Is there another pandas setting like `display.max_row` for this default view? How can I expand this to let's say the top and bottom 10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, use `display.min_rows`:

```
pd.set_option("display.min_rows", 20)
print(df)

# Output:
     0   1   2   3
0   18   8  12   2
1    2  13  13  14
2    8   7   9   2
3   17  19   9   3
4   14  18  12   3
5   11   5   9  18
6    4   5  12   3
7   12   8   2   7
8   11   2  14  13
9    6   6   3   6
..  ..  ..  ..  ..
90   8   2   1   9
91   7  19   4   6
92   4   3  17  12
93  19   6   5  18
94   3   5  15   5
95  16   3  13  13
96  11   3  18   8
97   1   9  18   4
98  13  10  18  15
99  16   3   5   9

[100 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: Great! This was almost too obvious :)